# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got error from my Sqlite Android. I have code like this:

```
public int UpdatePhotoUser(String foto_user, int metode) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        int update = 0;

        if (metode == 1) {
            values.put(Variabel.KEY_USER_PHOTO, foto_user);
            try {
                update = db.update(
                        Variabel.TABLE_USER,
                        values, null, null);
            } catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {

            }
        } else if (metode == 2 && getUserDetails(Variabel.KEY_USER_PHOTO).equals(foto_user)) {
            values.put(Variabel.KEY_USER_PHOTO, "");
            try {
                update = db.update(
                        Variabel.TABLE_USER,
                        values, null, null);
            } catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {

            }
        }

        db.close();
        return update;
    }
```

And I have Error at last line:

```
update = db.update(
                            Variabel.TABLE_USER,
                            values, null, null);
```

This the eror:

```
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor/databases/DB_KAMAR_DAGANG
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
            at com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor.database_content.DatabaseHandler.UpdatePhotoUser(DatabaseHandler.java:613)
            at com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor.fragments.PhotoUserFragment.removeRespone(PhotoUserFragment.java:985)
            at com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor.fragments.PhotoUserFragment.access$600(PhotoUserFragment.java:62)
            at com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor.fragments.PhotoUserFragment$12.onResponse(PhotoUserFragment.java:879)
            at com.ad.kamardagang.newseditor.fragments.PhotoUserFragment$12.onResponse(PhotoUserFragment.java:875)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**edited:**
exmple I call with :

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
 db.UpdatePhotoUser("http://a.png",1);
```

when. I **first** call metode **UpdatePhotoUser(String foto_user, int metode)**, but on **second** call its error. so how to fix it ?

Comment: can you post the code from where you are calling this UpdatePhotoUser() method, I mean full code of PhotoUserFragment.java and DatabaseHandler.java

Comment: post your code, where you calling this function

Comment: cek my question edited sir...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're closing the database at the end of the method:

```
db.close();
```

You don't need to do that. The database will be closed when the app is no longer used.

Anyway, there are better ways to manage the database. Search for tutorials about *ContentProvider* class, there are some useful resources out there.

Answer (score 0):

i think you Have Closed **db** object before update.

Answer (score 0):

You close the object at the end of the first call.

```
db.close();
```

It seems you use a personnal method to get the SQLiteDatabase

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Try with a singleton and test if instance is closed or not:

```
private Singleton()
{}

private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();


public static Singleton getInstance()
{   
    //Some code
    if(!INSTANCE.isOpen()){
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has similar issue try this it will resolve issue

```
if (db == null || !db.isOpen()) 
{
  dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this); //u can omit this but need to have an extra check dbHelper!=null
  db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```